# How is the default template of a custom control applied with out using "Themes\Generic.xaml ?"

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I created a custom content control with its default template. 
The template though is not located in the location "Themes\Generic.xaml" as it is supposed to be. Instead I placed it in a separate resource dictionary with a different name. 
It is merged along with other resource dictionaries in the App.xaml resource dictionary.

Running the code yielded no errors and the control is visible. I tested the application on other machines and the code ran just fine , I would like to point out that these machines are development machines.

Testing the application on the client machines (non development) then revealed some strange behaviour. The custom control was not visible; it would only be visible on 1 out 3 client machines.

I was able to fix the problem by putting the template in "Themes\Generic.xaml".

My question is how was it able to work without having to put the template in "Themes\Generic.xaml" ? I have searched on Google but I could find any clear cut explaination .

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

For your templates to be applied they need to be present in Themes\Generic.xaml.
The good news is that you may merge them here, which I find to be good practice, and makes your code cleaner. Often my generic.xaml consists of only this, one X.Generic.xaml for all your cust. controls.

Themes/Generic.xaml:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
...>
    <!-- Your custom controls split into separate files -->
    <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="/YourNamespace;component/Themes/ControlA.Generic.xaml" />
        <ResourceDictionary Source="/YourNamespace;component/Themes/ControlB.Generic.xaml" />
    </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Comment: That is exactly how I have done it to fix the issue , what I'm really curious about is that on my development machine it was able to work with out having to put it in "Themes/Generic.xaml". For example I create a control called "ControlA" located under "projectname.controls" and the template will be located under "resources/ControlADefault.xaml" then it will be merged in App.xaml

Comment: Then you will have to apply you template manually to my knowledge, why not simply just put it in Themes\Generic.xaml. You know the point of this right? You may have several themes. The standard way of handling this is as described above, which as stated allows you have different themes. WPF will scan this file/folder, and it's the kosher way of dealing with the matter.

Comment: Yes I understand , that is how I have done it currently it is now in Themes\Generic.xaml. But before I didn't know I had to put it there and I had put in a different location and it still worked. I am just curious as to why it worked on some machines

Comment: don't do it! :) Why swim against the stream and do things that you are not supposed to do? You have several good books that describes how this works.